# powershell, how to get firefox windows title and close one of them

Tags: powershell, firefox, windows-10, powershell-5.0

when I open multiple windows in firefox, they all run in the same process, but when I go in the task manager, the process can be *unfolded* and there is one line for each opened window with the name of the active tab visible. idem when I hover the mouse over the task bar, a tiny picture of each open window pops up with the name of the active tab.

I tried `get-process | where-object {$_.mainwindowhandle -ne 0} | select-object name, mainwindowtitle` but I only get the name of the front most window

how can I list with powershell the name of all firefox windows and close the one I want, based on its name (I can't kill the process as all windows run in the same process)?

do you have any clue for me?

PS. I don't speak C# and am not able to understand C# examples

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in Posh but it requires native API calls and its not very elegant. You should use [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com) for this, its one liner basically.

The right tool for the job.